# mysql multiple Insert where select many column from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data:

table1:

```
id  common_criteria        member_id
1       some                 1000
2       some1                 500
3       some                  100
4       some                  200
3       some1                2000
```

table2

```
id member_id
```

The `id` columns are `AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` on both tables

I need to insert into `table2` three new rows (in this case) where `common_criteria` from `table1` = 'some'

Expected result for table2:

```
id    member_id
1       1000
2       100
3       200
```

I have tried:

```
INSERT into table2 (`member_id`) 
VALUES (
 SELECT `member_id` FROM table1 WHERE common_criteria = 'some'
)
```

But I get a syntax error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT `member_id` FROM table1 WHERE common_criteria = 'some')'
>   at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the VALUES part when you want to get the results from a SELECT. Instead you can simplify it to this:

```
INSERT into table2 (`member_id`) 
   SELECT `member_id`
   FROM table1 
   WHERE common_criteria = 'some'
```

and it will insert all the rows returned by the SELECT.

---

Additional note (since people often ask this): If you had a scenario where some of the values are static every time, then you can do that too quite easily:

```
INSERT into table2 (`member_id`, `some_other_field`) 
   SELECT `member_id`, 'Static Text' 
   FROM table1 
   WHERE common_criteria = 'some'
```

In this case "Static Text" will be inserted every time into every row, no matter how many rows are returned (and inserted) as a result of the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (`member_id`) 
SELECT `member_id` FROM table1 WHERE common_criteria = 'some'
```

Comment: Thank's ...  You have upvote but I will accept ADyson answer because him have first